# how to change value of v-if condition of current item in loop (on click)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue.js app, I have a list of contacts in a v-for loop, each with a corresponding 'edit' button; I want to toggle the v-if="="!isEditingContact" condition for only the selected contact. I have the index of the button/contact to be edited, but I don't know how to toggle the 'isEditingContact' condition for the selected contact.

My component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container" id="project-edit">
        <section class="client-data">
            <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
            <dl v-if="!isEditingClient">
            <!-- SNIP-->
            </dl>
            <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
            <fieldset v-if="isEditingClient">
            <!-- SNIP -->
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button v-if=!isEditingClient id="edit-client" v-on:click="editMode">edit</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingClient v-on:click="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingClient v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
            </div>
        </section><!-- END .client-data -->

        <section class="gig-data">
            <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
            <dl v-if="!isEditingGig">
            <!-- SNIP-->
            </dl>

            <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
            <fieldset v-if="isEditingGig">
            <!-- SNIP-->
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button v-if=!isEditingGig id="edit-gig" v-on:click="editMode">edit</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingGig v-on:click="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingGig v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
            </div>
        </section><!-- END .gig-data -->

        <section class="contacts-wrapper">
            <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
            <dl>
                <dt>contacts:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul class="contacts">
                        <li v-if="!isEditingContact" v-for="(contact, ix) in project.contacts" v-bind:key="??">
                            {{ contact.name }}<br />
                            {{ contact.title }}<br />
                            {{ contact.email }}<br />
                            {{ contact.phone }}
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <button v-if=!isEditingContact id="edit-contact" v-on:click="editContact(contact, ix)">edit</button>
                                <button v-if=isEditingContact v-on:click="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
                                <button v-if=isEditingContact v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
                    <fieldset v-if="isEditingContact">
                    <!--
                        SNIP:
                        FORM TO BE DISPLAYED IN PLACE OF THE SELECTED CONTACT,
                        AND W/OUT HIDING OTHER CONTACTS
                    -->
                    </fieldset>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: [ "projectID" ],
        components: {
        },
        data () {
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                title: "Edit Project",
                subtitle: "ID: " + this.$route.params.id,
                project: {},
                contactInfo: {},
                workLocation: true,
                submitted: false,
                isEditingClient: false,
                isEditingGig: false,
                isEditingContact: false
            }
        }, // data
        created: function() {
            this.$http.get("https://xyz.dataworld.com/projects/" + this.id + ".json")
            .then(function(data) {
                return data.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                this.project = data;
            })
        }, // created

        methods: {
            addContactInfo: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.projectID = this.id;
                this.project.contacts.push(this.contactInfo);
                this.contactInfo = {};
            },
            editMode: function(e) {
                const buttonID = e.currentTarget.id;
                switch (buttonID) {
                    case "edit-client":
                        this.isEditingClient = !this.isEditingClient;
                        break;
                    case "edit-gig":
                        this.isEditingGig = !this.isEditingGig;
                        break;
                    // case "edit-contact": ... this is uselesss, since it would hide all contacts as it shows the form
                    //  this.isEditingContact = !this.isEditingContact;
                    //  break;
                    default:
                }
            },
            editContact: function(e) {
            },
            cancelEdit: function() {
                this.isEditingClient = false;
                this.isEditingGig = false;
                this.isEditingContacts = false;
            },
            post: function() {
                console.log(this.project);
                this.$http.post("https://sr-giglog.firebaseio.com/projects.json", this.project)
                    .then(function(data){
                        this.submitted = true;
                    }
            )} // post function
        } // methods
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commonly this is done by adding a flag to the individual objects in your list. In this case, an `editing` flag, or whatever you want to call it. You would initialize it with false. You can add this flag either server side or client side. If you want to do it client side it would look something like this:

```
this.$http.get("https://xyz.dataworld.com/projects/" + this.id + ".json")
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => {
    // add the editing property
    for (let contact of data.contacts)
      this.$set(contact, 'editing', false)

    this.project = data
  })
```

Then, use that property in your template.

```
<section class="contacts-wrapper">
  <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
  <dl>
    <dt>contacts:</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="contacts">
        <li v-if="!contact.editing" v-for="(contact, ix) in project.contacts" v-bind:key="??">
          {{ contact.name }}<br />
          {{ contact.title }}<br />
          {{ contact.email }}<br />
          {{ contact.phone }}
          <div class="buttons">
            <button v-if="!contact.editing" id="edit-contact" v-on:click="contact.editing = true">edit</button>
            <button v-if="contact.editing" v-on:click="contact.editing = false">cancel</button>
            <button v-if="contact.editing" v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
      <fieldset v-if="contact.edting">
         ...
      </fieldset>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I'm trying to implement your sugg but getting either error ('Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: project is not defined') or, a blank screen if I put this.project = data before the 'for (let ...' ... I'm working on it but if you have any further sugg, greately appreciated

Comment: @WhiskeyT.Foxtrot it was just a typo. Your property was project and I accidentally added the s.

Comment: Thank you again for steering me in the right direction. Besides my original question as to how to add an attribute to looped elements, I was < 100% clear on how the data was processed in the Promise/.then statements, but I have gained clarity on that as well, which I appreciate greatly. It was also necessary for me to modify my template structure somewhat so I will try to post the working version in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store editing contact's id and check that inside v-if.

If you stored the id of contact that is being edited in editingContactId then you can modify your code to this:

```
<ul class="contacts">
    <li v-for="(contact, ix) in project.contacts" v-bind:key="??">
        {{ contact.name }}<br />
        {{ contact.title }}<br />
        {{ contact.email }}<br />
        {{ contact.phone }}
        <div class="buttons">
            <button v-if="editingContactId!=contact.id" id="edit-contact" v-on:click="editContact(contact, ix)">edit</button>
            <button v-if="editingContactId==contact.id" v-on:click="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
            <button v-if="editingContactId==contact.id" v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. At the moment I think I prefer the approach I used in my answer, per @Bert, but this pattern/syntax is good know!

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, here's my revised, working solution (at least this reflects specifically what I was asking to achieve in my OP):

My component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container" id="project-edit">
        <section class="client-data">
            <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
            <dl v-if="!isEditingClient">
            <!-- SNIP-->
            </dl>
            <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
            <fieldset v-if="isEditingClient">
            <!-- SNIP -->
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button v-if=!isEditingClient id="edit-client" v-on:click="editMode">edit</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingClient v-on:click="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingClient v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
            </div>
        </section><!-- END .client-data -->

        <section class="gig-data">
            <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
            <dl v-if="!isEditingGig">
            <!-- SNIP-->
            </dl>

            <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
            <fieldset v-if="isEditingGig">
            <!-- SNIP-->
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button v-if=!isEditingGig id="edit-gig" v-on:click="editMode">edit</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingGig v-on:click="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
                <button v-if=isEditingGig v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
            </div>
        </section><!-- END .gig-data -->

        <section class="contacts-wrapper">
            <!-- show static if editMode FALSE -->
            <dl>
                <dt>contacts:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <li v-for="(contact, ix) in project.contacts">
                        <!-- show orig data if editMode FALSE -->
                        <div v-if="!contact.editingContact">
                            {{ contact.name }} ({{ ix }})<br />
                            {{ contact.title }}<br />
                            {{ contact.email }}<br />
                            {{ contact.phone }}
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <button v-if=!contact.editingContact id="edit-contact" v-on:click="contact.editingContact = true">edit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- show FORM if editMode TRUE -->
                        <fieldset v-if="contact.editingContact">
                            <!-- SNIP: FORM ... -->
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <!-- I realize that the v-if attributes are not necessary here -->
                                <button v-if=contact.editingContact v-on:click="contact.editingContact = false">cancel</button>
                                <button v-if=contact.editingContact v-on:click="post">save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </li>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: [ "projectID" ],
        components: {
        },
        data () {
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                title: "Edit Project",
                subtitle: "ID: " + this.$route.params.id,
                project: {},
                contactInfo: {},
                workLocation: true,
                submitted: false,
                isEditingClient: false,
                isEditingGig: false,
            }
        }, // data
        created: function() {
            this.$http.get("https://xyz.dataworld.com/projects/" + this.id + ".json")
                .then(data => data.json())
                .then(data => {
                    for (let contact of data.contacts) {
                        this.$set(contact, 'editingContact', false)
                    }
                    this.project = data;
                })
        }, // created

        methods: {
            addContactInfo: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.projectID = this.id;
                this.project.contacts.push(this.contactInfo);
                this.contactInfo = {};
            },
            editMode: function(e) {
                const buttonID = e.currentTarget.id;
                switch (buttonID) {
                    case "edit-client":
                        this.isEditingClient = !this.isEditingClient;
                        break;
                    case "edit-gig":
                        this.isEditingGig = !this.isEditingGig;
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            },
            editContact: function(e) {
            },
            cancelEdit: function() {
                this.isEditingClient = false;
                this.isEditingGig = false;
            },
            post: function() {
                console.log(this.project);
                this.$http.post("https://sr-giglog.firebaseio.com/projects.json", this.project)
                    .then(function(data){
                        this.submitted = true;
                    }
            )} // post function
        } // methods
    }
</script>
```

Now, if you'd all just stand by while I prepare my next twelve questions ...